# Find, copy and paste values after comparing cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. I want to find the header `Test Code 1` in `Sheet1` and the same header in `Sheet2`. Afterwards I want to check every number under `Test Code 1` in `Sheet1` and compare it to the number under `Test Code 1` in `Sheet2`. If the numbers are the same, I want to copy the cell to the respective cell in `Sheet2`. Since I want to change the code for further use, it has to work like shown below with the Find function and a loop.

[image]

```
Sub CompareV1()

Dim FindT1 As Range
Dim FindT2 As Range

Dim Values1 As Range
Dim Values2 As Range

Dim T1Column As Long
Dim T1Row As Long

Dim T2Column As Long
Dim T2Row As Long

Dim V1Column As Long
Dim V1Row As Long

Dim V2Column As Long
Dim V2Row As Long

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:FF")

        Set FindT1 = .Find(What:="Test Code 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set Values1 = .Find(What:="Values", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:FF")

        Set FindT2 = .Find(What:="Test Code 1", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set Values2 = .Find(What:="Values", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:FF")

        If Not FindT2 Is Nothing Then

        For x = 1 To 10

        T1Row = FindT1.Row + x
        T1Column = FindT1.Column

        T2Row = FindT2.Row + x
        T2Column = FindT2.Column

        V1Row = Values1.Row + x
        V1Column = Values1.Column

        V2Row = Values2.Row + x
        V2Column = Values2.Column

        If FindT1.Value = FindT2.Value Then

        Set Values1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(V1Row, V1Column)
        Set Values2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(V2Row, V2Column)

        Values1.Copy Values2

        Else

        End If

        Next x

        Else

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

For some reason it doesn't work properly. I don't know why. The current result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks a bit overcomplicated. Is there only one Values column and is it always next to "Text Code 1"?

Comment: No, it's complicated, because the further use requires it to work like that.

Comment: Why don't you try running code by Pressing F8. You will know what is happening at each step.

Comment: "the further use requires it to work like that" - what does that mean? This code could be greatly simplified to the same effect.

Comment: Aren't you asking the same question over and over on here with just slight differences? Just wondering why.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are comparing within the if statements the headers, you do increment the T1Row and the T2Column to step into the values, but you don't update the value of FindT1, by the time the code gets there I think it is still pointing to the headers therefore it is adjusted by one. I would change the if statement to something like:

```
if cells(T1Row, T1Column).value = cells(T2Row, T2Column).value Then
```

by the way the commenters are right - it could be greatly simplified:

```
    Dim orig_val As Variant
    Dim check_val As Variant

    For x = 1 To 10
        orig_val = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FindT1.Row + x, FindT1.Column).Value
        check_val = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(FindT1.Row + x, FindT1.Column).Value
        If orig_val = check_val Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Values2.Row + x, Values2.Column).Value = orig_val
        End If
    Next x
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rngFound1 As Range, rngFound2 As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    strSearch = "Test Code 1"

    Set rngFound1 = ws1.UsedRange.Find(What:=strSearch, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set rngFound2 = ws2.UsedRange.Find(What:=strSearch, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rngFound1 Is Nothing And Not rngFound2 Is Nothing Then

        With ws1
            LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rngFound1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            arr1 = .Range(.Cells(rngFound1.Row + 1, rngFound1.Column), .Cells(LastRow1, rngFound1.Column))
        End With

        With ws2
            LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rngFound2.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            arr2 = .Range(.Cells(rngFound2.Row + 1, rngFound2.Column), .Cells(LastRow2, rngFound2.Column))
        End With

        For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)

            For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)

                If arr1(i, 1) = arr2(j, 1) Then
                    ws2.Cells(rngFound2.Row + j, rngFound2.Column + 1).Value = ws1.Cells(rngFound1.Row + i, rngFound1.Column + 1).Value
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next j

        Next i

    Else

        MsgBox "Sheet1 or Sheet2 or both does/do not includes/include " & strSearch

    End If

End Sub
```